# Facebook iOS SDK not working

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

My class is a `FBRequestDelegate` and I'm not getting any errors on build yet I get nothing from `didFailWithError` or `didReceiveResponse`. I've been searching for close to a week now and simply cannot figure out what is wrong:

```
-(BOOL)postToFacebook:(NSString *)status{
    NSLog(@"Posting to Facebook with status: \"%@\"", status);

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [params setObject:status forKey:@"message"];

    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];

    params = nil;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Are you using ARC, and also how do you create the object postToFacebook is implemented in? I have had problems where my request delegate was being cleaned up because I didn't hold a sufficient reference to it in my own code.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up just switching my entire project over to Facebook's old REST API for the time being. I've had so many troubles with the Facebook iOS SDK while using ARC, it isn't even worth it anymore.